# How to fix 'pip3 and virtualenv not found in path'

Tags: python, windows, path

I'm trying to add virtualenv and pip3 to path in windows 10.

They're located in this folder:
[image: directory location]

I've added them to the path environment variable:
[image: path variable]

But I'm still getting the error when I try to use one of them:
[image]

EDIT: Restarting my computer fixed the problem.

Comment: Have you restarted after your changes? Try `echo %path%` to see if your path is also correct in your cmd

Comment: I'll try both, thanks for the troubleshooting tips.
EDIT: Restarting worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

No need add all three times.

Add only `Scripts` directory to `PATH` of system variables.

How you installed `virtualenv`? If No

Do this,

```
pip install virtualenv  # Have you tried this?
```

If yes,

Check it is present in installed packages or not,

like this

```
pip freeze
```

**Note:**
Don't forget to restart command prompt.